# How can I create a search form in rails to find object related to the current object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search

In my app, I have workflows and clients. Its a many-to-many relationship. Each client tends to have 30-40 workflows. In my clients show page I currently have a table to show all of the workflows for that client.

```
  <%- model_class = Client -%>
     <div class="page-header">
        <h1><%=t '.title', :default => @client.name %></h1>
     </div>
  ...

  <% @workflows %>

  <% @workflows.each do |workflow| %>
  ...
```

In my clients controller I have this to prepare objects for Show.

```
def show
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])

  @workflows_no_subs = Workflow.where(:client_id => @client.id, :requires_preconfig => 'true')    
  @workflows_raw = Workflow.where(:client_id => @client.id)
  @workflows = @workflows_raw.sort_by {|flow| flow.name}

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end

end
```

What I want to do is add a search box at the top of the page so the user can search for workflows within the client specific workflows and present the results.

What I found online pointed me to something like this in the view:

```
<%= form_tag clients_path(@client), :method => 'get' do %>
<h2> Search for Workflows </h2>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

With something like this in the controller:

```
@clients = Client.search(params[:search])
```

But everything I find online talks about that being in the index method, and I cant figure out or find any good explanation how to do this within my show method (which is where I'm just assuming it seems like it would need to go).

I'm trying to figure out how best to accomplish this via the rails way, and also if maybe I should be trying to do this with something like JQuery instead of just rails.

The current result I am seeing if I attempt to search now is:

```
 Processing by ClientsController#index as 
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"sdsdf"}
 Client Load (53.3ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE (name LIKE '%sdsdf%' OR re_workflow_ident LIKE '%sdsdf%' )
 PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "re_workflow_ident" does not exist
```

Comment: The current result of attempting a search is:

Comment: What you should do is Workflow.search(params[:search]) and add the client_id to the where clause

Comment: You should add this in your `show` action if you want to see it on that view.  There is a good Railscast on this http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax.  Whether or not you implement with Ajax is a matter of preference.

Comment: Mario, do you mean Like this? Workflow.search(params[:search]).where(:client_id => @client.id)